# JavaScript recursive search in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I am trying to return a specific node in a JSON object structure which looks like this

```
{
    "id":"0",
    "children":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "children":[...]
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "children":[...]
        }
    ]
}
```

So it's a tree-like child-parent relation. Every *node* has a unique ID.
I'm trying to find a specific *node* like this

```
function findNode(id, currentNode) {

    if (id == currentNode.id) {
        return currentNode;
    } else {
        currentNode.children.forEach(function (currentChild) {            
            findNode(id, currentChild);
        });
    }
}
```

I execute the search for example by `findNode("10", rootNode)`. But even though the search finds a match the function always returns `undefined`. I have a bad feeling that the recursive function doesn't stop after finding the match and continues running an finally returns `undefined` because in the latter recursive executions it doesn't reach a return point, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Please help!

Comment: since it is answer, I just want to point out that foreach loop can't stop in javascript. do not use foreach in algorithm.

Comment: Why are you performing a search on a JSON object in the first place?  You should maybe consider doing the search in the place where the JSON object was generated, hopefully the database.

Comment: @jmb.mage because in the real world you often have to solve tasks which don't have ideal circumstances and whose details are out of your reach. This is one of them.

Comment: see [deepdash](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash)

Comment: @milahu deepdash started getting developed 4 years after the question was posted and this functionality definitely doesn't need a library to be slapped on top of it to achieve the requested results..

Answer (score 61, accepted):

When searching recursively, you have to pass the result back by returning it. You're not returning the result of `findNode(id, currentChild)`, though.

```
function findNode(id, currentNode) {
    var i,
        currentChild,
        result;

    if (id == currentNode.id) {
        return currentNode;
    } else {

        // Use a for loop instead of forEach to avoid nested functions
        // Otherwise "return" will not work properly
        for (i = 0; i < currentNode.children.length; i += 1) {
            currentChild = currentNode.children[i];

            // Search in the current child
            result = findNode(id, currentChild);

            // Return the result if the node has been found
            if (result !== false) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        // The node has not been found and we have no more options
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add an additional check to the for loop (i.e., for (i = 0; currentNode.children !== undefined && i < currentNode.children.length; i += 1)) to avoid the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at leaf nodes where "children" do not exist.

Comment: breaks with can't find length of undefined. it's a document object.

Comment: I am searching like that for a child by name in all bins in premierepro extendscript now :)

Comment: Here's a similar solution, but with less code https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205610/3666971

Comment: You should probably return null instead of false, if you return an object of type T at the other place.  But JavaScript's dynamic types are very forgiving.

Answer (score 5):

```
function findNode(id, currentNode) {

    if (id == currentNode.id) {
        return currentNode;
    } else {
        var result;
        currentNode.children.forEach(function(node){
            if(node.id == id){
                result = node;
                return;
            }
        });
        return (result ? result : "No Node Found");
    }
}
console.log(findNode("10", node));
```

This method will return the node if it present in the node list. But this will loop through all the child of a node since we can't successfully break the `forEach` flow. A better implementation would look like below.

```
function findNode(id, currentNode) {

    if (id == currentNode.id) {
        return currentNode;
    } else {
        for(var index in currentNode.children){
            var node = currentNode.children[index];
            if(node.id == id)
                return node;
            findNode(id, node);
        }
        return "No Node Present";
    }
}
console.log(findNode("1", node));
```

Comment: Dear @Triode, You define `result` but never use it.

Comment: @Mehr88sh Sorry, Rectified!!

Answer (score 4):

I use the following

```
var searchObject = function (object, matchCallback, currentPath, result, searched) {
    currentPath = currentPath || '';
    result = result || [];
    searched = searched || [];
    if (searched.indexOf(object) !== -1 && object === Object(object)) {
        return;
    }
    searched.push(object);
    if (matchCallback(object)) {
        result.push({path: currentPath, value: object});
    }
    try {
        if (object === Object(object)) {
            for (var property in object) {
                if (property.indexOf("$") !== 0) {
                    //if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property)) {
                        searchObject(object[property], matchCallback, currentPath + "." + property, result, searched);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(object);
        throw e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can write

```
searchObject(rootNode, function (value) { return value != null && value != undefined && value.id == '10'; });
```

Now this works on circular references and you can match on any field or combination of fields you like by changing the `matchCallback` function.

Comment: the match callback is a great idea and I also like that you get the path as well as the object. Cheers!

Comment: It works, thank you. You should mention that in order to search for a specific node you should change this part:
   if (property.indexOf("NameOfTheNodeYouAreLookingFor") !== 0) {}

And also to change to return object; instead of return result;

Comment: @atfede the reason i return `result` is to allow for more then one hit. I'm a bit unsure what you mean with `if (property.indexOf("NameOfTheNodeYouAreLookingFor") !== 0) {}`

Answer (score 3):

Since this old question has been brought back up, here's a different approach.  We can write a fairly generic `searchTree` function which we then use in a `findId` function.  `searchTree` does the work of traversing the object; it accepts a callback as well as the tree; the callback determines if a node matches.  As well as the node, the callback is supplied two functions, `next` and `found`, which we call with no parameters to signal, respectively, that we should proceed or that we've found our match.  If no match is found, we return `null`.

It looks like this:

```js
const searchTree = (fn) => (obj) =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.length == 0
      ? null
      : searchTree (fn) (obj [0]) || searchTree (fn) (obj .slice (1))
    : fn (
      obj,
      () => searchTree (fn) (obj .children || []),
      () => obj
    )

const findId = (target, obj) => searchTree (
  (node, next, found) => node.id == target ? found () : next(),
) (tree)


const tree = {id: 1, name: 'foo', children: [
  {id: 2, name: 'bar', children: []}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'baz', children: [
    {id: 17, name: 'qux', children: []}, 
    {id: 42, name: 'corge', children: []},
    {id: 99, name: 'grault', children: []}
  ]}
]}


console .log (findId (42, tree))
console .log (findId (57, tree))
```

This code is specific to the structure where subnodes are found in an array under the property `children`.  While we can make this more generic as necessary, I find this a common structure to support.

There is a good argument that this would be better written with mutual recursion.  If we wanted, we could get the same API with this version:

```js
const searchArray = (fn) => ([x, ...xs]) =>
  x === undefined
    ? null
    : searchTree (fn) (x) || searchArray (fn) (xs)

const searchTree = (fn) => (obj) =>
  fn (
    obj,
    () => searchArray (fn) (obj .children || []),
    (x) => x
  )
```

This works the same way.  But I find the code cleaner.  Either should do the job, though.

Answer (score 2):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for our data processing needs. It's conceptually very simple, but allows for a lot of cool stuff. Here is how you could solve your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const findNode = (id, input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value.id === id
})(input);

const data = { id: '0', children: [{ id: '1', children: [ { id: '3', children: [] }, { id: '4', children: [] } ] }, { id: '2', children: [ { id: '5', children: [] }, { id: '6', children: [] } ] }] };

console.log(findNode('6', data));
// => { id: '6', children: [] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: Several other answers here mention that they work on circular objects.  Does object-scan take this into account?

Comment: Yes. However since it's a performance tradeoff you need to handle it explicitly. Ie you could simply add `breakFn: ({ isCircular }) => isCircular`

Comment: I do love how simple object-scan makes this problem.  I'm not yet convinced that I want to try it in my own code, I may get there soon though.

Answer (score 2):

Similar questions were answered several times, but I  just want to add a universal method that includes nested arrays

```js
const cars = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'toyota',
  subs: [{
    id: 43,
    name: 'supra'
  }, {
    id: 44,
    name: 'prius'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jeep',
  subs: [{
    id: 30,
    name: 'wranger'
  }, {
    id: 31,
    name: 'sahara'
  }]
}]

function searchObjectArray(arr, key, value) {
  let result = [];
  
  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    if (obj[key] === value) {
      result.push(obj);
    } else if (obj.subs) {
      result = result.concat(searchObjectArray(obj.subs, key, value));
    }
  });
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}

searchObjectArray(cars, 'id', '31') 

searchObjectArray(cars, 'name', 'Jeep')
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I really liked a tree search! A tree is an extremely common data structure for most of today's complex structured tasks. So I just had similar task for lunch too. I even did some deep research, but havent actually found anything new! So what I've got for you today, is "How I implemented that in modern JS syntax":

```
// helper
find_subid = (id, childArray) => {
    for( child of childArray ) {
        foundChild = find_id( i, child ); // not sub_id, but do a check (root/full search)!
        if( foundChild ) // 200 
            return foundChild;
    }
    return null; // 404
}

// actual search method
find_id = (id, parent) => (id == parent.id) : parent : find_subid(id, parent.childArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive structure search, modification, keys/values adjustments/replacement.

### Usage Example:

```js
const results = []; // to store the search results

mapNodesRecursively(obj, ({ v, key, obj, isCircular }) => {
    // do something cool with "v" (or key, or obj)
    // return nothing (undefined) to keep the original value

    // if we search:
    if (key === 'name' && v === 'Roman'){
        results.push(obj);
    }

    // more example flow:
    if (isCircular) {
        delete obj[key]; // optionally - we decide to remove circular links
    } else if (v === 'Russia') {
        return 'RU';
    } else if (key.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'foo') {
        return 'BAR';
    } else if (key === 'bad_key') {
        delete obj[key];
        obj['good_key'] = v;
    } else {
        return v; // or undefined, same effect
    }
});
```

### Tips and hints:

You can use it as a search callback, just return nothing (won't affect anything) and pick values you need to your Array/Set/Map.

Notice that callback is being run on every leaf/value/key (not just objects).

Or you can use the callback to adjust particular values and even change keys. Also it automatically detects circular loops and provides a flag for you to decide how to handle them.

### The code

(uses ES6)

Function itself + some example demo data

```js
function mapNodesRecursively(obj, mapCallback, { wereSet } = {}) {
    if (!wereSet) {
        wereSet = new Set();
    }

    if (obj && (obj === Object(obj) || Array.isArray(obj))) {
        wereSet.add(obj);

        for (let key in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                continue;
            }

            let v = obj[key];

            const isCircular = wereSet.has(v);

            const mapped = mapCallback({ v, key, obj, isCircular });
            if (typeof (mapped) !== 'undefined') {
                obj[key] = mapped;
                v = mapped;
            }

            if (!isCircular) {
                mapNodesRecursively(v, mapCallback, { wereSet });
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

let obj = {
    team: [
        {
            name: 'Roman',
            country: 'Russia',
            bad_key: 123,
        },
        {
            name: 'Igor',
            country: 'Ukraine',
            FOO: 'what?',
        },
        {
            someBool: true,
            country: 'Russia',
        },
        123,
        [
            1,
            {
                country: 'Russia',
                just: 'a nested thing',
                a: [{
                    bad_key: [{
                        country: 'Russia',
                        foo: false,
                    }],
                }],
            },
        ],
    ],
};

// output the initial data
document.getElementById('jsInput').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

// adding some circular link (to fix with our callback)
obj.team[1].loop = obj;

mapNodesRecursively(obj, ({ v, key, obj, isCircular }) => {
    if (isCircular) {
        delete obj[key]; // optionally - we decide to remove circular links
    } else if (v === 'Russia') {
        return 'RU';
    } else if (key.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'foo') {
        return 'BAR';
    } else if (key === 'bad_key') {
        delete obj[key];
        obj['good_key'] = v;
    } else {
        return v;
    }
});

// output the result - processed object
document.getElementById('jsOutput').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Recursive structure modification, keys/values adjustments/replacement</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>
      Replacing "Russia" values with "RU"
    </li>
    <li>
      Setting the value "BAR" for keys "FOO"
    </li>
    <li>
      Changing the key "bad_key" to "good_key"
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="col">
    <h4>BEFORE</h4>
    <pre id="jsInput"></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4>AFTER</h4>
    <pre id="jsOutput"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```