# How to find a object in a nested array using recursion in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested

Consider the following deeply nested array:

```
const array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "bla",
        children: [
            {
                id: 23,
                name: "bla",
                children: [{ id: 88, name: "bla" }, { id: 99, name: "bla" }]
            },
            { id: 43, name: "bla" },
            {
                id: 45,
                name: "bla",
                children: [{ id: 43, name: "bla" }, { id: 46, name: "bla" }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "bla",
        children: [
            {
                id: 232,
                name: "bla",
                children: [{ id: 848, name: "bla" }, { id: 959, name: "bla" }]
            },
            { id: 433, name: "bla" },
            {
                id: 445,
                name: "bla",
                children: [
                    { id: 443, name: "bla" },
                    {
                        id: 456,
                        name: "bla",
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 97,
                                name: "bla"
                            },
                            {
                                id: 56,
                                name: "bla"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "bla",
        children: [
            {
                id: 263,
                name: "bla",
                children: [{ id: 868, name: "bla" }, { id: 979, name: "bla" }]
            },
            { id: 483, name: "bla" },
            {
                id: 445,
                name: "bla",
                children: [{ id: 423, name: "bla" }, { id: 436, name: "bla" }]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

How would I grab a certain object by key that might be deeply nested, using recursion?
I have tried this, but this won't work for nesting deeper than 2 levels, it then just returns `undefined`:

```
const findItemNested = (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => {
    for (const i of arr) {
        console.log(i.id);
        if (i.id === itemId) {
            return i;
        }
        if (i[nestingKey]) {
            findItemNested(i[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey);
        }
    }
};
```

The result should be:

`const res = findItemNested(array, 959, "children"); >> { id: 959, name: "bla" }`

This can perhaps also be achieved using `.find`, or just to flatten the array (by the children key), but using recursion seems like the most logical solution to me. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: You need to `return` the inner `findItemNested` call, otherwise its return value is discarded.

Comment: Yep, that's one thing I've been doing wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might use a recursive `reduce`:

```js
const array=[{id:1,name:"bla",children:[{id:23,name:"bla",children:[{id:88,name:"bla"},{id:99,name:"bla"}]},{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:45,name:"bla",children:[{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:46,name:"bla"}]}]},{id:12,name:"bla",children:[{id:232,name:"bla",children:[{id:848,name:"bla"},{id:959,name:"bla"}]},{id:433,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:443,name:"bla"},{id:456,name:"bla",children:[{id:97,name:"bla"},{id:56,name:"bla"}]}]}]},{id:15,name:"bla",children:[{id:263,name:"bla",children:[{id:868,name:"bla"},{id:979,name:"bla"}]},{id:483,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:423,name:"bla"},{id:436,name:"bla"}]}]}];

const findItemNested = (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => (
  arr.reduce((a, item) => {
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.id === itemId) return item;
    if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
  }, null)
);
const res = findItemNested(array, 959, "children");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I don't understand when "a" var in reduce function is affected ?!

Comment: The `a` is the accumulator, the value returned from the last iteration. If truthy, a match has been found.on a past iteration, and gets returned to the next iteration. If falsy, a match hasn't been found yet, so the `reduce` either returns the current item if it's a match: `return item` or it searches for a recursive match with `return findItemNested(...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. same i was looking for .

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
function findByIdRecursive(array, id) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const element = array[index];
    if (element.id === id) {
      return element;
    } else {
      if (element.children) {
        const found = findByIdRecursive(element.children, id);

        if (found) {
          return found;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this is one simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

You might also use recursion with `Array.find` like below

```js
const array=[{id:1,name:"bla",children:[{id:23,name:"bla",children:[{id:88,name:"bla"},{id:99,name:"bla"}]},{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:45,name:"bla",children:[{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:46,name:"bla"}]}]},{id:12,name:"bla",children:[{id:232,name:"bla",children:[{id:848,name:"bla"},{id:959,name:"bla"}]},{id:433,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:443,name:"bla"},{id:456,name:"bla",children:[{id:97,name:"bla"},{id:56,name:"bla"}]}]}]},{id:15,name:"bla",children:[{id:263,name:"bla",children:[{id:868,name:"bla"},{id:979,name:"bla"}]},{id:483,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:423,name:"bla"},{id:436,name:"bla"}]}]}];


function findById(arr, id, nestingKey) {
  
  // if empty array then return
  if(arr.length == 0) return
  
  // return element if found else collect all children(or other nestedKey) array and run this function
  return arr.find(d => d.id == id) 
      || findById(arr.flatMap(d => d[nestingKey] || []), id) 
      || 'Not found'
}

console.log(findById(array, 12, 'children'))

console.log(findById(array, 483, 'children'))

console.log(findById(array, 1200, 'children'))
```

Answer (score 3):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for most of our data processing. It's awesome for all sorts of things, but does take a while to wrap your head around. This is how one could answer your question:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (data, id) => objectScan(['**(^children$).id'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parent',
  useArraySelector: false,
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(data);

const array=[{id:1,name:"bla",children:[{id:23,name:"bla",children:[{id:88,name:"bla"},{id:99,name:"bla"}]},{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:45,name:"bla",children:[{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:46,name:"bla"}]}]},{id:12,name:"bla",children:[{id:232,name:"bla",children:[{id:848,name:"bla"},{id:959,name:"bla"}]},{id:433,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:443,name:"bla"},{id:456,name:"bla",children:[{id:97,name:"bla"},{id:56,name:"bla"}]}]}]},{id:15,name:"bla",children:[{id:263,name:"bla",children:[{id:868,name:"bla"},{id:979,name:"bla"}]},{id:483,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:423,name:"bla"},{id:436,name:"bla"}]}]}];

console.log(find(array, 12));
// => { id: 12, name: 'bla', children: [ { id: 232, name: 'bla', children: [ { id: 848, name: 'bla' }, { id: 959, name: 'bla' } ] }, { id: 433, name: 'bla' }, { id: 445, name: 'bla', children: [ { id: 443, name: 'bla' }, { id: 456, name: 'bla', children: [ { id: 97, name: 'bla' }, { id: 56, name: 'bla' } ] } ] } ] }
console.log(find(array, 483));
// => { id: 483, name: 'bla' }
console.log(find(array, 959));
// => { id: 959, name: 'bla' }
console.log(find(array, 1200));
// => undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: `object-scan` is great! i didnt know it before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const array=[{id:1,name:"bla",children:[{id:23,name:"bla",children:[{id:88,name:"bla"},{id:99,name:"bla"}]},{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:45,name:"bla",children:[{id:43,name:"bla"},{id:46,name:"bla"}]}]},{id:12,name:"bla",children:[{id:232,name:"bla",children:[{id:848,name:"bla"},{id:959,name:"bla"}]},{id:433,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:443,name:"bla"},{id:456,name:"bla",children:[{id:97,name:"bla"},{id:56,name:"bla"}]}]}]},{id:15,name:"bla",children:[{id:263,name:"bla",children:[{id:868,name:"bla"},{id:979,name:"bla"}]},{id:483,name:"bla"},{id:445,name:"bla",children:[{id:423,name:"bla"},{id:436,name:"bla"}]}]}];
const findItemNested = (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  return a.length
    ? a
    : c.id === itemId
      ? a.concat(c)
      : c[nestingKey]
        ? a.concat(findItemNested(c[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey))
        : a
}, []);
const res = findItemNested(array, 959, "children");

if (res.length) {
  console.log(res[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use recursive find by level, it'll try to find the item in array and then call itself with the children of each item in the array:

New browsers will have Array.prototype.flatten but in this case I've added the flatten function separately.

```js
const array = [{"id":1,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":23,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":88,"name":"bla"},{"id":99,"name":"bla"}]},{"id":43,"name":"bla"},{"id":45,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":43,"name":"bla"},{"id":46,"name":"bla"}]}]},{"id":12,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":232,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":848,"name":"bla"},{"id":959,"name":"bla"}]},{"id":433,"name":"bla"},{"id":445,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":443,"name":"bla"},{"id":456,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":97,"name":"bla"},{"id":56,"name":"bla"}]}]}]},{"id":15,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":263,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":868,"name":"bla"},{"id":979,"name":"bla"}]},{"id":483,"name":"bla"},{"id":445,"name":"bla","children":[{"id":423,"name":"bla"},{"id":436,"name":"bla"}]}]}];


const flatten = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce((result, item) => result.concat(item), []);
const findBy = (findFunction, subItemsKey) => (array) =>
  //array is empty (can be when children of children of children does not exist)
  array.length === 0
    ? undefined //return undefined when array is empty
    : array.find(findFunction) || //return item if found
      findBy(findFunction, subItemsKey)(//call itself when item is not found
        flatten(
          //take children from each item and flatten it
          //([[child],[child,child]])=>[child,child,child]
          array.map((item) => item[subItemsKey] || []),
        ),
      );
const findChildrenById = (array) => (value) =>
  findBy((item) => item.id === value, 'children')(array);
const findInArray = findChildrenById(array);

console.log('found', findInArray(99));
console.log('not found', findInArray({}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate through your objects and then need to be parse each object using recursion. Try the answer mentioned here:  [JavaScript recursive search in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222599/javascript-recursive-search-in-json-object)

code:

`function findNode(id, currentNode) {
    var i,
        currentChild,
        result;

```
if (id == currentNode.id) {
    return currentNode;
} else {

    // Use a for loop instead of forEach to avoid nested functions
    // Otherwise "return" will not work properly
    for (i = 0; i < currentNode.children.length; i += 1) {
        currentChild = currentNode.children[i];

        // Search in the current child
        result = findNode(id, currentChild);

        // Return the result if the node has been found
        if (result !== false) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    // The node has not been found and we have no more options
    return false;
}
```

}`