# What exactly is it about reduce and not being able to break out of it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why can't I break out of a `reduce` in Javascript?

Seems a simple `return` or even a `throw` will not break it at all. Exactly why does it need to loop through all of the values?

Comment: You can refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144406/how-to-break-on-reduce-method

Comment: Why do you want to break out of reduce for?

Comment: @AngelosChalaris It's not. I asked what about its design made the original implementers say "you will always go through each item"? That question treats the act of breaking a `reduce` and how to. I'm interested on the "why can't I".

Comment: @coolpasta why *wouldn't* it go through each item? All of the iteration methods never break - `map`, `forEach`, `filter`, etc. It absolutely makes sense because you'd use them when you don't want to stop the iteration. So, your question is backwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's what it's designed to do - it will always loop through all items in the array, just like most other array methods like `forEach` and `map`.

If, past some point, you want to effectively ignore what comes afterwards, just return the current accumulator, for example:

```js
const partialSum = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, num) => {
  if (a > 3) {
    return a;
  }
  return a + num;
}, 0);

console.log(partialSum);
```

If you want to *find* an element in the array instead, you should use `.find`, which will terminate the loop as soon as a match is found:

```js
const arr = [
  { prop: 'foo' },
  { prop: 'bar' },
  { prop: 'baz' }
];
const foundBar = arr.find((obj) => {
  console.log('iteration');
  return obj.prop === 'bar';
});
```

A `throw` *will indeed* break out of a `.reduce` (although you shouldn't use errors for control flow):

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((a, num) => {
  console.log('iteration');
  if (num > 2) {
    throw new Error();
  }
});
```

Comment: Returning the accumulator...isn't that, in other words (which for me makes more sense), to say "enough adding to the accumulator, just return it"?

Comment: Sure, if the accumulator happens to be the sort of thing that is continually added to or mutated, though occasionally it isn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390440/how-to-find-a-object-in-a-nested-array-using-recursion-in-js

Answer (score 1):

If your codebase seems to frequently need breaking inside of a `reduce`, it might be a better idea to use a `for` loop instead. However, if you absolutely have to use `reduce` and need to break from inside of it, you can use one of the following options:

- Return the current accumulator without changes on every element after the point where you need to break.
- Use `throw` to break out of the `reduce` method, although this is not recommended.
- Mutate the `4th` argument of the reducer function, which is the array being iterated over. If you mutate it to an empty array, `reduce` will exit. Be careful with this, as it can have unwanted side effects.

`reduce` is designed to iterate over all of the elements in an array, therefore this is why it's not easy, common or recommended to break out of it. This is also why there are so many other array manipulation methods, as `reduce` *can* in theory replace all of them given the proper function, however it presents certain limitations that other array methods do not.