# search in nested array of objects js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have a nested array of objects and I'm trying to find a string inside of it. Once I find it I'd like to return the containing object.
**Here's my code:**

```js
const myArray = [{
    label: "Home",
    last: "odlir",
    children: [{
        label: "Home 1",
        last: "odlir1",
        children: [{
          label: "Home 2",
          last: "odlir2"
        }, {
          label: "Home 3",
          last: "odlir3"
        }]
      },
      {
        label: "Home 4",
        last: "odlir4",
        children: [{
          label: "Home 5",
          last: "odlir5"
        }, {
          label: "Home 6",
          last: "odlir6"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "dash",
    last: "gom"
  },
  {
    label: "principal",
    last: "asd"
  }
];

function contain(obj, string) {
  if (obj == null)
    return false;

  if (obj.last == string)
    return obj;

  if (typeof obj.children == 'undefined')
    return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
    if (contain(obj.children[i], string))
      return obj;
  }
  return false;
}

function getObject(array, string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (contain(array[i], string)) {
      return array[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log('test', getObject(myArray, 'odlir6'));
```

I'm getting back the object I want, parent object and even grandfather.
Here's is a stackblitz of this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hgchmx

Comment: what do you want by arrays? the index or the outer array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript recursive search in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222599/javascript-recursive-search-in-json-object)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks i'm going to try that answer

Comment: @NinaScholz actually i want the object that contains the string i'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and store the paren object for every nested call.

1. Declare `result`, later this variable contains the parent object.
2. Check if the given variable is not `null` but an object. Exit if not.
3. Iterate the values from the object with a short circuit and

   - check if the value is equal to the wanted string, then return with the assignment of the object.
   - otherwise return the result of the recursive call.

```js
function getObject(object, string) {
    var result;
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
    Object.values(object).some(v => {
        if (v === string) return result = object;
        return result = getObject(v, string);
    });
    return result;
}

const
    array = [{ label: "Home", last: "odlir", children: [{ label: "Home 1", last: "odlir1", children: [{ label: "Home 2", last: "odlir2" }, { label: "Home 3", last: "odlir3" }] }, { label: "Home 4", last: "odlir4", children: [{ label: "Home 5", last: "odlir5" }, { label: "Home 6", last: "odlir6" }] }] }, { label: "dash", last: "gom" }, { label: "principal", last: "asd" }];

console.log(getObject(array, 'odlir6'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this is almost what i want i'd like to get just {
    "label": "Home 6",
    "last": "odlir6"
  }

Comment: It works thank you however can you explain your code a litle?